# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchtext.legacy'

Tags: pytorch

https://colab.research.google.com/github/saic-mdal/lama/blob/master/colab/LaMa_inpainting.ipynb#scrollTo=RwXRMaNHW4r5

Was checking out this code on colab. but getting error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchtext.legacy'

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/output/3_mask.png'